# How to display emoji character in TimelinePlot label as it appears in a string?

Tags: plotting, labeling

I would like to render an emoji in the label of a TimelinePlot DateObject.

E.g.

```
pubemoji = FromCharacterCode[{9999, 65039}] <> " "; (* space added otherwise glyph clipped *)
{pubemoji, TimelinePlot[
  Style[
   Labeled[
    DateObject[],
    pubemoji <> "<- different glyph!"
    ]
   ]
  ]}
```

Where I expect the emoji to render in the form returned by `FromCharacterCode[{9999, 65039}]`.

It however renders a different glyph entirely.

[image]

Whereas other emoji render closer to what is returned in `FromCharacterCode` in the notebook frontend.

Comment: What version are you using? Might have been a fixed bug recently.

Comment: Using version 12.3.1.0 (Mac OS X) x86 64 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In version `12.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 24, 2021)`, both of them are rendered correctly.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, when exported to PDF, *both of them* get rendered as black&white characters.

[image: PDF export]

I think the *easiest* solution is to **rasterize the glyph**.

```
pubemoji = Rasterize[Style[FromCharacterCode[{9999, 65039}], FontSize -> 20]]; 
{pubemoji, TimelinePlot[Style[Labeled[DateObject[], Row[{pubemoji, "<- same glyph"}]]]]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that this is note a quirk of the `TimelinePlot`, but appears to be a general problem of rendering "non-standard" glyphs.

Comment: Different result on "12.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 8, 2021)" https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFZ5C.png

Comment: On 12.3.1 Mac OS X x86 the emoji do not render whatsoever in PDF/PNG or any graphic format i've tried. For the emoji, it looked like it was vectorized but now that i think about it likely not. I'll use your rasterize method (thank you) and likely that will help get the emoji into the output format. thanks again.